# nLocktime for Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core, locktime

I was reading this while doing some research: https://github.com/achow101/wallet-fingerprinting/blob/main/fingerprints.md and had some questions:

What is the default nLocktime for a transaction in Bitcoin Core?

Was it ever changed because I remember it being zero at some point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **What is the default nLocktime for a transaction in Bitcoin Core?**

### Wallet source code

In version 23.0 the `wallet\spend.c` includes this

```c
/**
 * Return a height-based locktime for new transactions (uses the height of the
 * current chain tip unless we are not synced with the current chain
 */
static uint32_t GetLocktimeForNewTransaction(interfaces::Chain& chain, const uint256& block_hash, int block_height)
{
    uint32_t locktime;
    // Discourage fee sniping.
    //
    // For a large miner the value of the transactions in the best block and
    // the mempool can exceed the cost of deliberately attempting to mine two
    // blocks to orphan the current best block. By setting nLockTime such that
    // only the next block can include the transaction, we discourage this
    // practice as the height restricted and limited blocksize gives miners
    // considering fee sniping fewer options for pulling off this attack.
    //
    // A simple way to think about this is from the wallet's point of view we
    // always want the blockchain to move forward. By setting nLockTime this
    // way we're basically making the statement that we only want this
    // transaction to appear in the next block; we don't want to potentially
    // encourage reorgs by allowing transactions to appear at lower heights
    // than the next block in forks of the best chain.
    //
    // Of course, the subsidy is high enough, and transaction volume low
    // enough, that fee sniping isn't a problem yet, but by implementing a fix
    // now we ensure code won't be written that makes assumptions about
    // nLockTime that preclude a fix later.
    if (IsCurrentForAntiFeeSniping(chain, block_hash)) {
        locktime = block_height;
```

So bitcoin core sets locktime to the current block height to discourage fee sniping.

### Release Notes

[Release notes for version 0.11](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/release-notes/release-notes-0.11.0.md) (updated Aug 2015) say

> Wallet
>
> #2340 811c71d Discourage fee sniping with nLockTime

---

### When using RPCs

Locktime is zero when transaction is created manually using RPCs like `createpsbt` or `createrawtransaction`. Else a random nearest block height is used in bitcoin core. (Source: OP experimentation)

---

### Documented meaning of Locktime

It may help to consider the meaning of Locktime

The [Protocol Documentation](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#tx) says

> The block number or timestamp at which this transaction is unlocked:

| Value | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Not locked |
| < 500000000 | Block number at which this transaction is unlocked |
| >= 500000000 | UNIX timestamp at which this transaction isunlocked |

> If all TxIn inputs have final (0xffffffff) sequence numbers then
> lock_time is irrelevant. Otherwise, the transaction may not be added
> to a block until after lock_time (see NLockTime).

If we look at some transactions in block 654,915 we can see that most transactions have either no lock (0) or a block number ...

C> blockchain -file blk02300.dat -block 100

Transactions in block 00000000000000000002FC97B15D50E38CEB0C6A83DA4344CE836B01FC841EEA

| No. | V | Type | Ins | Outs | Lock | Satoshi | Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Segwit | 1 | 3 | 0 | 743862941 | 36FD1CE479F30EF1CA1E44F7B2CF63D21C5CA8DBB04C1D5551A26735DB0266B8 |
| 2 | 1 | Legacy | 1 | 2 | 0 | 99992768 | D889E605D3DD5986C89A66F446FEB228A7BCE58278C5F62EED579DB730148001 |
| 3 | 1 | Segwit | 3 | 1 | 0 | 7685144 | 268705614DCB68AED6A3750172F445EDCE6179D149BE769AF08D253B7A21F22D |
| 4 | 2 | Legacy | 2 | 1 | 0 | 7907240 | F3E237ED279F039DA0FAAAF5285362FAD18BADFA9E97455007F39D2C0D275112 |
| 5 | 2 | Legacy | 6 | 36 | 654900 | 5739473461 | 8F5B79B4CAC8EEF4525996E7B0B1B02DF83F9199816F27BA7FDD3E57C098D069 |
| 6 | 2 | Segwit | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1310690 | 819977BFF99145BCD38024FE0A3BC5B03A82A0A5FAA4A8A8073DB2D1893CC4D0 |
| 7 | 1 | Segwit | 1 | 3 | 0 | 1376557 | 378F17EB675E8998D9E1B4283E2AA3E8FB0213827296E6FAB54C8ED78C5E3777 |
| 8 | 1 | Segwit | 2 | 5 | 0 | 558656062 | 800C2349DF26295A3AFFBAD35CBB98D82A26AD7F69C8A6BF78ACFE4483414130 |
| 9 | 2 | Legacy | 1 | 2 | 0 | 9845471 | 119308B6C68AFB33D621202B704EB3D77867C7CDF7496FBDDB3176EA33481992 |
| 10 | 2 | Legacy | 1 | 2 | 0 | 9845471 | 618CD9BBE59448307C2941183A6AB7AD9DB1837B5139BDFC578108D5B710D980 |
| 11 | 1 | Segwit | 1 | 1 | 0 | 3469300 | 28AAF790C652C2B07F67FF4FD0E37997CC562B8DB92633DF5E8684399E15DACB |
| 12 | 1 | Legacy | 1 | 1 | 0 | 375540 | 1EE38AFEB454980F694E654713D01188EBCC91BFC4213874CAA5376C0B37CD66 |
| 13 | 1 | Legacy | 1 | 1 | 0 | 223479 | FE02E255EF4200A1D16C5DEBB442933C4A22EA544E55452B905D47EA99ED9675 |
| 14 | 1 | Legacy | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1127700 | CB227B308DC46B4B312BAE6704D6D3B7E2FC8CE3CB7B17E26BB1DB9EE5BAEFB8 |
| 15 | 1 | Segwit | 1 | 1 | 0 | 877025 | EA1871DC8D71A2C8B9224DC3937DF90324AFBD3D266EBBD27AC7A4FE2FB15F89 |
| 16 | 1 | Segwit | 1 | 2 | 0 | 40824845 | 2C0607F2B4FA6A15CABBEDABAFDA198CC4A98D18EA134963CAC08E26FF31C3E8 |
| 17 | 2 | Legacy | 1 | 2 | 654914 | 550200 | 24EBB2CB89EAE962E89939D48BD35D731791D1ABE8AC911FC8909BCEB299D9F9 |
| 18 | 2 | Legacy | 1 | 2 | 654914 | 134435250 | A7E6E408D619DEF6E43D00B03ACFD247DE7268EB34E751D437BB03961954DFF6 |
| 19 | 2 | Segwit | 1 | 2 | 654862 | 463598 | DAF9BF664D3C4CFEB1D625351922C51867EE1C2A648BBE5281D5505D7DE54ECF |
| 20 | 1 | Segwit | 2 | 2 | 0 | 6316861 | 7FBD3F3079E0AA2404D28800329974F2D9C2D1115E3BE39DAD4898CFC123C8BC |

I'd guess most wallets make the default 0 since my quick look at this block seemed to show about 90% with that value.

---

Footnote: If we assume general use of block height in locktime is consistent with the approach in Bitcoin core, we can probably use this to see how fee rate affected delays in getting a transaction mined. Transactions 17 and 18 above were mined quickly, transaction 19 probably had to wait 52 blocks? (8-9 hours?)

Comment: Based on my findings, these are the wallets that use nearest block height: bitcoin core, bitcoin knots, electrum, sparrow and specter. Others used zero. I am not sure but I think I have done a few transaction using bitcoin core in which it was zero.

Comment: Answer Updated: Bitcoin core sets locktime to current block height to discourage fee sniping.

Comment: I just found that locktime is zero when transaction is created manually using RPCs like `createpsbt` or `createrawtransaction`. Else a random nearest block height is used in bitcoin core. Maybe you can add this information in the answer.

Comment: Happy to do that. Done.